# FQL - Does the query work? 

Tags: facebook-fql, comments

When I query the number of comments for a link using:

```
SELECT comment_count 
   FROM link_stat 
   WHERE url ='http://www.facebook.com/pages/K-F-C/337958765652'
```

I get `3` as result.

But when I query the contents of each comment using:

```
SELECT post_fbid, fromid, object_id, text, time FROM comment 
WHERE object_id IN 
  (SELECT comments_fbid 
   FROM link_stat 
   WHERE url ='http://www.facebook.com/pages/K-F-C/337958765652')
```

I got empty result: `[]`

Does anyone know what's going on? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use post_fbid instead of object_id

The doc for post_fbid says "The object_id of this comment. This can be used for querying likes for this comment or replies to this comment if the comment came from the comments plugin."